# fancybox and jquery overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using this basic template with a slider in the home but when I add a simple fancybox script for a single image, the fancybox doesn't work.

What of these js is overlapping fancybox?

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js?v=3.1.3"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

    <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

    <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.mp-slider').cycle({
                pager: '#mp-pags',
                timeout:7000,
                pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
                });
            function pagerFactory(index, slide) {
                var titles = []
                titles[0] = $("#mp-pags-cont li:eq(0)").text()
                titles[1] = $("#mp-pags-cont li:eq(1)").text()
                titles[2] = $("#mp-pags-cont li:eq(2)").text()
            return '<li><a href="#">'+(titles[index])+'</a></li>';
            }; 

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: the second ready() method may be overlapping the closing brackets of cycle() ... you actually can wrap all your pulgin initializations in a single ready() method.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find out with something like this is to comment out one script at a time until you find the one causing the issue. Then you can look more closely at that script and figure out where the conflict is.

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
```

may be problematic. don't you want to call:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory(a,b)
```

with parameters?